# C# - custom IComparer<T> that takes an argument as input

Tags: c#, icomparer

I have a list of Points (x,y) that I want to sort by their polar angle with respect to a reference point which I calculate as the average point of all points in the list.
How can I set up IComparer so that I can pass the reference point to it for calculating the polar angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the reference point ahead of time and pass it to the constructor of your `IComparer`:

```
class PointComparer : IComparer<Point>
{
    private readonly Point referencePoint;

    public PointComparer(Point referencePoint)
    {
        this.referencePoint = referencePoint;
    }
    public Int32 Compare(Point x, Point y)
    {
        // Compare using referencePoint
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var ordered = myList.OrderBy(x => x, new PointComparer(calculatedReferencePoint));
```

I used `OrderyBy` and not `Sort` because the latter is considered not a stable sort when we refer to the documentation.

Comment: You can also derive from the _class_ type `Comparer<Point>`. You will still need a `Compare(Point, Point)` method (this time an `override` of the inherited `abstract` method from the base class), but the advantage is you get support for both `IComparer<Point>` and the old non-generic `IComparer`.

Comment: When you use `OrderBy`, you can also skip the custom class and just capture (close over) that reference point in the `Comparison<Point>` delegate (lambda). That would be `myList.OrderBy(x => /* expression involving x and calculatedReferencePoint */)`. If you really need a comparer, you can get it with `Create`, as in `Comparer<Point>.Create(x => /* expression involving x and calculatedReferencePoint */)`, again eliminating the need for writing the custom class yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

**Option A**

The reference point must be part of your `Point` object. So that in your `Point`'s Compare method, you could take it into consideration to calculate the angle and compare the objects.

```
public int IComparer.Compare(Point x, Point y)  {
  var angleX = Utilities.CalculateAngle(x.ReferencePoint);
  var angleY = Utilities.CalculateAngle(y.ReferencePoint);

  if (angleX < angleY) return -1;
  if (angleX == angleY) return 0;
  if (angleX > angleY) return 1;

  // Or simply "return angleX - angleY;"
}
```

**Option B**

The `Angle` should be already calculated in your point. Make the `Point` an immutable structure and calculate the angle at the time of instantiate of the structure. Then just `OrderBy` that property.

i.e.

```
public struct Point
{
  public double Angle { get; private set; }

  public Point(double referencePoint, double x, double y)
  {
    // TODO: Calculate Angle
  }
}

points.OrderBy(p => p.Angle);
```

Comment: Your **Option A** `IComparer.Compare` cause compilation error, because not every path return value.

Comment: k, then just `return angleX - angleY;`, as I commented in the code

Comment: Is not angle supposed to be some floating point type? AFAIK, no of them have implicit conversion to `int`. So, you still have error here.

Comment: I didn't really put much thought into that, it's more of a pseudo-code

Comment: @PetSerAl The best option is `return angleX.CompareTo(angleY);`. It works for both `int`, `float`, and `double` (and more). And even in the `int` case it is better, if there is a risk the subtraction Hristo Yankov suggests, can overflow (a difference exceeding `int.MaxValue` can become negative, and similarly for `MinValue`). Also semantically or "logically" it expresses what we want.